# How to properly use the result from a get query from a Room database

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, android-room, kotlin-coroutines

In my app I have a list of workouts, and at one point a want to get the name of one workout using its id in the Room database. For this, I made a SQL query in the DAO class to get the workout name using its id. my main problem is how to get it from the `ViewModel` to the view. The app uses coroutines.

DAO function:

```
@Query(
    "SELECT workout_name FROM workout_table " +
            "WHERE id = :workoutId"
)
suspend fun getWorkoutName(workoutId: Long): String
```

Repository function:

```
@WorkerThread
suspend fun getWorkoutName(workoutId: Long): String {
    return database.workoutDao().getWorkoutName(workoutId)
}
```

ViewModel function:

```
fun getWorkoutName(workoutId: Long): MutableLiveData<String> {
    val workoutName = MutableLiveData<String>()
    CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
        workoutName.postValue(repository.getWorkoutName(workoutId))
    }
    return workoutName
}
```

View function (inside the fragment .kt class):

```
private fun setUpAppBar() {
    binding?.apply {
        viewModel.getWorkoutName(currentWorkoutId!!).observe(viewLifecycleOwner) {
            editWorkoutTopAppbar.title = it
        }
    }
}
```

Assume 'editWorkoutTopAppbar' is a textView.

This code works, but notice the `ViewModel` and the view. In the `ViewModel` I return a `MutableLiveData` variable and observe it in the view, I do this to use the variable when the value is ready.
I realize I can get all the workouts at the beginning of the app and filter them to get the specific one, but my goal is to query the database.

What is a cleaner or more efficient way to get this value from the `ViewModel`?

Comment: How does the view interact with the xml? Or is it a `View` class?

Comment: I edited my question to make this clear, the last piece of code I presented is inside a view (fragment .kt) function, and 'editWorkoutTopAppbar' you can think of as a textView

Comment: If you're starting with your app, or in the Android development altogether, I suggest you switch to Jetpack Compose, coroutines and Flows (instead of LiveData). It takes a little effort at the beginning to get the new declarative mindset, but it will save you a lot of work later.

https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose

Comment: @DissidentDev I believe I am using coroutines with 'CoroutineScope()', am I not? Also I am using flow in another part of the app.

Comment: All I meant is Compose/coroutines/Flow is a good pack that simplifies things when compared to Views/coroutines/LiveData -not saying you are not using coroutines or flow.  Just sharing some advice about something that served me well :)

Comment: @DissidentDev That was not sarcasm lol, I was actually doubting if what I'm using is coroutines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my projects with LiveData and ViewModel I utilise [DataBinding](https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/data-binding) for this. I set the `ViewModel` as a variable inside the xml and bind the variables of the `ViewModel` to the views:

```
<layout>

    
    <data>

        <variable
            name="viewModel"
            type="path.ViewModel" />
    </data>

    <TextView
        android:text="@{viewModel.variableName}" />

</layout>
```

Fragment:

```
val binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, layoutRes, container, false)
binding.setVariable(BR.viewModel, viewModel)
```

Possible code improvement:

You could also directly return a `LiveData` from your Dao:

Dao:

```
@Query(
    "SELECT workout_name FROM workout_table " +
            "WHERE id = :workoutId"
) 
fun getWorkoutName(workoutId: Long): LiveData<String>
```

Repo:

```
fun getWorkoutName(workoutId: Long): LiveData<String> = 
  database.workoutDao().getWorkoutName(workoutId)
```

ViewModel:

```
// would always return only a LiveData instead of MutableLiveData so only the ViewModel can manipulate its value
fun getWorkoutName(workoutId: Long): LiveData<String> =
        workoutName.postValue(repository.getWorkoutName(workoutId))
```

On Coroutines:

Inside a `ViewModel` you can also use `viewModelScope` for Coroutines.

Comment: I think return a LiveData looks like a good option. I prefer not to use the viewModel in the .xml file. How would I use that liveData in view .kt file, should I still use .observe() ?

Comment: yes, I would say `.observe(LifecycleOwner){}` is the way.

Comment: got it, I'll wait some time to see if there's a better way, otherwise I'll mark yours as the answer.

Comment: I just realized you're not launching the coroutine in the viewModel in your response. The coroutine is the reason I used mutableLiveData so I don't see how your post answers my question.

Comment: My point with the code improvement is that Room can already return you a `LiveData` object, so you do not have to create one yourself and fill it by using `Coroutines`. The LiveData will update itself if the result of the query changes.

Comment: Will the Room query still be done in a background thread with your method? Doing the query in a background thread is the purpose of me using a coroutine.

Comment: Yes, source: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room/async-queries#livedata

Comment: I just read that the query will trigger everytime the database changes, not only if the result of the query changes. So you need to add `distinctUntilChanged` to not get notified all the time. Maybe if you only need to get the title once your one-shot request with `suspend` is better.

Comment: When working with `LiveData` I started a small lib containing my utility classes to solve some problems I had. Maybe you run into the same: https://github.com/DanielKnauf/livedata-kit

Comment: That's actually very useful, I'll look more into it but I think I'll go with your method.